# ActionScript 3.0 Flashvars

Tags: actionscript-3, flashvars

I have tried following things to access the FlashVars from HTML in the flash movie.

- Added the Flashvars in embed tag
- added the FlashVars in param tag
- added the FlashVars in JavaScript code generated by the Adobe Flash compiler
- Tried to access the FlashVars by using: root.loaderInfo.parameters.param_name and root.loaderInfo.parameters["param_name"]

But still I am not able to access the FlashVars. Can somebody guide me to the correct solution.

Comment: Did you instantiate it like this in AS3? `var paramObj:Object = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters;`

Comment: I tried this:

HTML:
flashvars="var1=val1&var2=val2&var3=val3"

ActionScript:
var paramObj:Object = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters;
var v1:String = paramObj["var1"];
var v2:String = paramObj.var1;
var text:TextField = new TextField();
text.text = "v1:"+v1+" _ v2:"+v2;
addChild(text);

still not working. Also the code is not inside any class or function(If that is a problem)

Comment: where are you wanna reach the flashvars? 
I can reach them by root.loaderInfo.parameters.paramName in the main class's which is connected to the stage and extends Sprite.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried embedding the swf with swfobject? is has a really simple syntax to pass flashvars.

to access them, I use:

```
var params:Object = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters;
var var1:String = params['var1'];
```